# How to import statement in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.text.EditText;
```

I can't import anything, when I press `ALT + Enter` it appeared create test instead of import class, variable and all that. How to import the syntax above?

Comment: Did you check my ans if u solve it than mark it as answer..so other user can get benifit of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows/Linux**

To import you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which ask for each thing, after you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept it.

If you want to change this behaviour to organize all imports go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Auto Import` -> `Java` and:

- change `Insert imports on paste` for `All`
- check `Add unambigious imports on the fly`

**Mac**

To import you can use <kbd>[image: option mac]</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which ask for each thing, after you have to press <kbd>[image: option mac]</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept it.

To change all behaviour are same steps but location is in `Android studio` > `Properties`...

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Shift+O to organize imports.