# i can't resolve the errors symbol from firebase authentification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i try to do a firebase connection with email and password, but i ah two symbol errors when i try to build.

the first one come from the AnotherActivity.class i don't know how to resolve it

```
public void updateUI(FirebaseUser account){

    if(account != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"U Signed In successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class));

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"U Didnt signed in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and the second come from EmailPasswordActivity.this

```
private void callsignin(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("success", "signInWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("failed", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

i think i need to write something in the manifest file but i don't what. Thank you for your attention and I hope you can help me

errors :
[image]

settings : [image]

import :

[image]

Comment: Can you point out what is the unresolved error show?

Comment: like this @Abhimanyu ?

Comment: Are they part of your project? If yes, have you imported them in this Activity?

Comment: I'm not really comfortable with android and java, what do you mean by imported them in activity ?can you explain me how to do that ? @Abhimanyu

Comment: Check if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: maybe it's the solution but how the import don't work i do like the refer post you sent to me . @Abhimanyu

Comment: can you share the import statements?

Comment: i added more information @Abhimanyu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the import statements are missing for `AnotherActivity` and `EmailPasswordActivity`.

At the top of your file, just below the package line, add these lines:

```
import <package_name>.AnotherActivity
import <package_name>.EmailPasswordActivity
```

For Android Studio shortcuts, Please refer to this post on how to use import in Android.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731266/9636037

Comment: how do i know the package_name ?

Comment: i imported this but i don't know by why replace "<package_name>" do you have any idee ? @Abhimanyu

Comment: <package_name> is used as a placeholder to refer to your package name, since we don't know your package structure. If you have imported it, it should work now.

Comment: Yeah i know but i use the code from firebase and i don't have the package name @Abhimanyu

Comment: Not clear what you are conveying. Is the issue resolved?

Comment: If not, have you imported the activities as mentioned in the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223298/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-norage).